# Is there any numerical derivative method that not limited by $\Delta h$?

Tags: analysis, numerical-methods

The numerical derivatives usually involve something like finite difference
$$
\frac{f(x+h) -f(x-h)}{2h} , h=\delta
$$
where $\delta$ was a small number. However, the specification of how small $\delta$ was is rather "arbitrary", in the sense that it may change from a function to another, and this method does not produce an estimate of the error function automatically. This is essentially the mean value theorem.

I'm thinking about the root finding algorithm such as the newton's method, etc.. Those algorithm used the iterative method which is much more flexible and does not involve the specification of $\delta$ and also stop with a threshold $\epsilon$ that mimic the error function. Is it possible to do something similar but does not involve the specification of $h$ and also have an estimation of the error $\epsilon$?

Is there any numerical derivative method that not limited by $\Delta h$?

Answer (score 3):

A series expansion around $x$ leads to even derivatives cancelling and an error based on the odd derivatives: $$
D(x,h)=\frac{f(x+h) -f(x-h)}{2h} =f'(x)+\tfrac 16 f'''(x) h^2+\tfrac {1}{120} f^{(5)}(x)h^4+\dots
$$
If we assume that $h$ is small enough, then we just need an estimate of the magnitude of the third derivative.

Let's suppose that we've evaluated the derivative twice -- once using $h$ and once using $ah$ for $0<a<1$. The second evaluation, and the difference between the two:$$
\begin{align}
D(x,ah)&=\frac{f(x+ah) -f(x-ah)}{2ah} =f'(x)+\tfrac 16 f'''(x) a^2 h^2+\tfrac {1}{120} f^{(5)}(x)a^4 h^4+\dots\\
D(x,h)-D(x,ah)&=\tfrac 16 f'''(x) (1-a^2 )h^2+\tfrac {1}{120} f^{(5)}(x)(1-a^4 )h^4+\dots\\
\frac{D(x,h)-D(x,ah)}{1-a^2}&=\tfrac 16 f'''(x) h^2+\tfrac {1}{120} f^{(5)}(x)(1+a^2 )h^4+\dots\\
&=D(x,h)-f'(x)+\tfrac {1}{120} f^{(5)}(x)a^2 h^4+\dots
\end{align}
$$

So for small $a$ and $h$, this gives you a pretty good way to evaluate the error in your derivative estimate.

I'm sure you could improve on this general approach.

The problem to watch out for, though, is that on a computer, rounding errors will start to dominate for small enough $h$. This approach is only useful well before that, because rounding errors look like steps.

Comment: There are many papers which derivative evaluation using cauchy integral

Comment: This (rather simple) idea has traditionally the name "Richardson extrapolation". One could use a third value to confirm if the identified leading error term actually dominates the error. If $h$ is too large, the higher-order terms can not be neglected, if $h$ is too small, floating-point errors will dominate.

Comment: Previous comment was cut: It should read: There are many papers which evaluate $n$th order derivatives by using the Cauchy integral relation $f^{(n)} (z) = \dfrac{n!}{2 \pi i } \oint_C \dfrac{f(w)}{(w - z)^{n + 1}} \, dw, \ \ n = 0, 1, 2, ... $ using numerical integration.

Comment: @KevinPWalker I think the round error does matter in the case I needed. I had another post on stackoverflow(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76469656/how-to-tell-how-small-h-is-the-in-the-finite-difference ) where, to avoid the rounding error, the lowest upper bound for the second order derivative was required. However, the lowest upper bound for the higher order derivatives was not known in general, and I'm not sure how to deal with it in the high precession computation.

Comment: The Cauchy integral relation does look better, but how to make sure that the numerical result was real? Does $(w-z)$ going to make introduce limits in the precession?

Comment: The original paper was by Lyness and Moler and this is referenced in https://sinews.siam.org/Details-Page/differentiation-without-a-difference. The simple idea presented in this short article might be useful. They demonstrate that  $h$ can be taken at very small values, provided the numerical implementation can use complex numbers.

Comment: Some snippets of code are given in https://gist.github.com/higham.